# mlab resetting database password

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab

I am using mLab on Heroku to host my database, and I forgot my database password.
I could not find anything about resetting my database password except for the following from the mLab website:

"it is possible that you’re mistakenly using the username and password that you use to log into your mLab account rather than the database user’s username and password. This is a common point of confusion because they are not necessarily the same."

[Here is the full page](http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help)

Does anyone know of a way to reset the *database* password (not my user password) on mLab?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I solved my own issue by running Heroku config on the project that was using the database, which gave the password (something that I definitely did not set).

Turns out the database password is set by Heroku. That was quite frustrating.

Comment: I want to kiss your footprints duuude!!!! Saved my life, I burned all of my day for googleing this idiot bug... I wish god bless you!!!!

Comment: Is there any way to change this password?

Answer (score 7):

Just to add slightly to the accepted answer of this post:

Go to the "Settings" tab of your selected application and select "Reveal Config Vars"

Your MongoDB username and password will be in the the `MONGODB_URI`:

`mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XXXXXX.mlab.com:13320/heroku_XXXXXX`